# Middleman paths not working on subdirectory

Tags: html, ruby, hyperlink, path, middleman

So, this is my first middleman project and I'm struggling with how middleman manages links.

As it is, I've set it up on a github page. All my assets are working, so I got that right, but the paths leading to each pages fail on account of the website being on a subdirectory.

Basically root/directoryname/index.html works but every link goes back one directory, so where I should have root/directoryname/page.html I get root/page.html.

[Here, have a link to see it live](http://benrajalu.github.io/portfoliov3/)

Here's what my config.rb looks like :

```
# Reload the browser automatically whenever files change
configure :development do
activate :livereload
end

# Methods defined in the helpers block are available in templates
# helpers do
#   def some_helper
#     "Helping"
#   end
# end

set :css_dir, 'css'

set :js_dir, 'js'

set :images_dir, 'img'

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # For example, change the Compass output style for deployment
  activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  activate :minify_javascript

  # Enable cache buster
  activate :asset_hash

  # Use relative URLs
  activate :relative_assets

  activate :directory_indexes

  # Or use a different image path
  # set :http_prefix, "/Content/images/"
end

activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.method = :git
  # Optional Settings
  # deploy.remote   = "custom-remote" # remote name or git url, default: origin
  # deploy.branch   = "custom-branch" # default: gh-pages
  # deploy.strategy = :submodule      # commit strategy: can be :force_push or :submodule, default: :force_push
end

data.works.each do |item|
  proxy "/references/#{item.clean}.html", "/work.html", :locals => { :code => item }, :ignore => true
end

helpers do
    # Sets the html class to 'active' when the link url is equal to the current page being viewed.
    # Use just like the link_to helper.
    # <%= magic_link_to 'Home', '/index.html' %>
    def magic_link_to(link, url, opts={})
        current_url = current_resource.url
        if current_url == url_for(url) || current_url == url_for(url) + "/"
            opts[:class] = "active"
        end
        link_to(link, url, opts)
    end
end
```

And here's what my main menu looks like:

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li id="logo"><% link_to '/index.html' do %><span>ben</span> rajalu<% end %></li>
        <li id="homeLink"><%= magic_link_to 'home', '/index.html' %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= magic_link_to 'services', '/services.html' %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= magic_link_to 'références', '/references.html' %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= magic_link_to 'a propos', '/a-propos.html' %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#" class="offTrigger" data-target="#contactBar">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What do you guys think ? What have I missed ?

Comment: As of Dec 2015, you should use 'link_to' instead of 'magic_link_to'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a basic issue with deploying Middleman projects to Github Pages.

The problem is that Github Pages deploy websites to subfolders, so when you have an absolute link, e. g. `<a href="/services.html">`, it will always point to a wrong location.

You need to switch Middleman to a relative links mode. Add this to your `config.rb`:

```
set :relative_links, true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed "that simple" :)

Comment: Will do as soon as I get enough rep to enable the feature!